# Can I use Siri, but prevent Maps on iOS from automatically starting the route?

Tags: iphone, maps

When I use Siri to ask iOS Maps to find a route (for example "Map a route to 123 Main St."), Maps displays the whole route for a second or so, then starts navigation, which makes it very difficult to see any part of the route except my current location.

(Entering the destination directly in Maps has the behavior I want, but that's an extra step it would be nice to avoid.)

Is there a way to use Siri, but prevent navigation from starting until I've had a chance to review the route?

Comment: This would be useful. I do 'get directions', wait for it to start navigating, end route, press destination button...and *then* it will show the three route choices you actually wanted in the first place :\ I've got so used to this faff that I do it before I get in the car - otherwise I've the additional step of "no, dammit, I'm not driving yet!"

Answer (score 2):

This procedure works well for me:

1. Open Maps and enter a place or address
2. Tap on the address/place you want to go to
3. Tap on the big blue button that gives you the duration of the trip
4. You should get a map with one or more routes at top and a list of those routes at the bottom
5. Tap on one of the durations on the left **NOT** the big "go" button on the right
6. Maps will display written directions including mileage

Or if you prefer

4. Place two fingers on the map and zoom in to view a birds-eye view of the suggested routes.

The only time it goes right to navigation is by pressing the green "Go" button. And even then you can zoom out on the starting point to see the whole route in map form.

Comment: Thanks!  When I open Maps first and enter a destination, it does function as you describe. 

I've been using Siri to launch Maps ("Map a route to 123 Main St.")  In that case, I get the behavior I described.

Answer (score 1):

> which makes it very difficult to see any part of the route except my current location.

The trick is to learn how to view your route after it's started.

You can click the overview button to see the whole route, or pull down the black bar at the top to see the step by step.

Driving Directions in Maps:
https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/get-driving-directions-ipha84a94043/ios

Overview & Turn List in Maps:
https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/view-a-route-overview-or-a-list-of-turns-iph1b3553719/16.0/ios/16.0

Comment: Thanks! The icon on the overview button is incomprehensible - I'd never have figured that out without help!